# How to include CMS page in the phtml page in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, template, cms-pages

I want to include the `CMS Page` in a `phtml` template. How can I achieve this? Can anyone help me over here?

Comment: Do you mean to show the contents of cms page in phtml?

Comment: yes i want to show the content of cms page content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the cms page content on your phtml page then write the following code:

**Method 1(by page identifier):**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$content = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory')->create();
$content->load('your-page-identifier', 'identifier');
echo $content->getContent();
```

**Method 2(by page ID):**

```
$page_id = YOUR_PAGE_ID;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$content = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory')->create();
$content->load($page_id);
echo $content->getContent();
```

Comment: Can we get the sofware code and then if the code matches then only we need to show this page can we do this...?

Comment: What do you mean by software code?

Comment: I'm downloading the zip file when a link  is clicked in CMS page content. And I wnat to hide content if the software id in null. how can we achive dis.

Comment: how do you get the software id? Can you add how do you get software id?